# Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,....a_n\geq0$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3+....+a_n=2m$,then prove that the greatest possible value of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i.a_{i+1}$.

Tags: inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,....a_n\geq0$ and $a_{n+1}=a_1$ with $a_1+a_2+a_3+....+a_n=2m$,then find the greatest possible value of $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ a_i\cdot a_{i+1}$$

I tried Cauchy-Schwarz but did not achieve success.How should I get its greatest value. Please suggest me some method.The answer given in the book is $m^2$.

Comment: Did you try Lagrange multiplier?

Comment: Upper limit of sum is $n$given not $n-1$@jameselmore

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia, sorry for not running that change by you first. You just didn't define a value for $a_{n+1}$, so the limit doesn't make much sense

Comment: The last term of this summation would be $a_n*a_{n+1}$ in which $a_{n+1}$ does not exist.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia, I see how you define $a_{n+1}$ now. Is there any information given on how $n$ compares with $m$?

Comment: @jameselmore,i did not define $a_{n+1}$.It is edited by Ewan Delanoy.

Comment: @jameselmore,i did not understand why he made that edit.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia You have to tell us what $a_{n+1}$ is. If the edit by Ewan is incorrect, you can also edit the question. But if $a_{n+1} \neq a_1$, there is basically no constraint on $a_{n+1}$ and the question is quite pointless.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia I corrected your question. As several people commented, your problem doesnt make sense if $a_{n+1}$ is not defined

Comment: If $a_1=a_2=a_3=\frac{2m}{3}$ then $\sum_{i=1}^{3}\ a_i.a_{i+1}=\frac{4m^2}{3}\ne m^2.$ So, the answer in your book is not correct, unless something more is missed. Could you want to bound $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\ a_i.a_{i+1}?$

Comment: @mfl No. The sum will be $\frac{4m^2}{9}$, not $\frac{4m^2}{3}$. It is strictly small than $m^2$.

Comment: @Asydot The sum is $\frac{4m^2}{9}+\frac{4m^2}{9}+\frac{4m^2}{9}=\frac{4m^2}{3}.$

Comment: @mfl Oh, now I get it... the question should have a assumption such as $n>3(n \geq 4)$. My proof have the same mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The question is equivalent to proving that
$$4(a_1a_2+a_2a_3+...+a_na_1) \leq (a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2.$$

Yes, we can prove it. WLOG, let $a_1=\max \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$, then
$$\begin{eqnarray}
4(a_1a_2+a_2a_3+...+a_na_1) 
&\leq& 4a_1(a_2+a_4+a_5+...+a_n)+4a_2a_3 \\
&\leq& 4(a_1+a_3)(a_2+a_4+a_5+...+a_n) \\
&\leq& (a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2. \text{(AM-GM)}
\end{eqnarray}$$

The equality holds if and only if $a_1=a_2=m, a_3=a_4=...=a_n=0$.

**Edited:**

However, this argument works only if $n>3$. If $n=3$, mfl has given a counterexample such that $a_1=a_2=a_3=2m/3$. 
To see what is wrong, notice that if $n>3$, $a_3$  won't appear in this part of the third formula $(a_2+a_4+a_5+...+a_n)$ and the proof works well. However, once we consider $n=3$, then $a_n=a_3$ - something wrong happens. As a result, the inequality doesn't holds anymore.

For $n=1$, it is trivial, since the sum is fixed. It equals to $a_1^2=4m^2$.

For $n=2$, it is still trivial. You only need to use $\text {AM-GM}$ inequality: $$a_1a_2+a_2a_1=2a_2a_1\leq \frac{(a_1+a_2)^2}{2}=2m^2.$$ The equality holds if and only if $a_1=a_2=m$.

For $n=3$, $a_2+a_3=2m-a_1$.
$$\begin{eqnarray}
a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_1
&=&a_1(2m-a_1)+a_2a_3 \\
&\leq& a_1(2m-a_1)+\frac{(2m-a_1)^2}{4} \\
&=&\frac{-3a_1^2}{4}+ma_1+m^2 \\
&=&-\frac{3}{4}(a_1-\frac{2m}{3})^2+\frac{4m^2}{3} \\
&\leq& \frac{4m^2}{3}.
\end{eqnarray}$$
The equality holds if and only if $a_1=a_2=a_3=\frac{2m}{3}$.

Comment: @mfl There is indeed a mistake in my answer (and the question). See the addition part in answer.

Comment: @mfl The argument has been fixed and now I think you can see that I didn't bound wrong formula. ;)